# Turn IPTables Flush off CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, firewall

I made some changes to my iptables in a centOS machine. I noticed once I shut the server off it flushes all my iptables and goes back to the default. Is there a way to turn that off?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, sort of, you have to save the current ruleset

```
service iptables save
```

This will write to the file /etc/sysconfig/iptables.

Comment: This is a cool feature to know about. I started to use shorewall instead but in the future it might be nice to just try this.